# Как восстановить EFI раздел?

Tags: linux, grub, uefi, windows-11

После перезагрузки openSUSE Tumbleweed (ядро 6.0.0-1) меня встретил `grub rescue`:

```
grub-rescue > ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd2)
grub-rescue > insmod gpt_part
error: no such partition
```

Отправляюсь в UEFI, и там катастрофа:

```
Select Boot Option:
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd # флешка с Ventoy
ventoy.efi
```

Пропали GRUB и Windows 11!

Гружу Kubuntu Live. Ну и ловлю Kernel Panic на `blkid`. Гружу Linux Lite: тут blkid уже прекрасно работает, и все разделы на месте. fsck.fat тоже особо не ругается. Через gparted проверяю - esp метка на EFI разделе на месте. Переназначаю метку - проблема не исчезает. Загружаю AdminPE - да все диски на месте:

```
/dev/sda1  Ventoy     C: exFAT
/dev/sdb1  EFI        D: FAT32   
/dev/sdc1  linuxboot  E: ext2
/dev/sdb2  Windows 11 F: NTFS
/dev/sdd1  disk_d     G: ext2
/dev/loop0 AdminPE    H: iso9660
```

Захожу в диск и пробую bootrec:

```
Admin@AdminPE-cmd (D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot) # bootrec /fixboot
```

Не помогает вернуть хотя бы Windows-овый загрузчик

Ну, пробую вернуть GRUB на место:

```
root@linuxlite6-live: ~ # mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc2 /mnt
root@linuxlite6-live: ~ # mount -t ext2 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/boot
root@linuxlite6-live: ~ # mount -t vfat /dev/sdb2 /mnt/boot/efi
root@linuxlite6-live: ~ # mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
root@linuxlite6-live: ~ # mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
root@linuxlite6-live: ~ # mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
root@linuxlite6-live: ~ # mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
root@linuxlite6-live: ~ # chroot /mnt
root@opensuse-tumbleweed: ~ # grub2-install
Installing for x86_64-efi.
Installation finished. No error occured.
```

А все равно GRUB лезет с grub-rescue. Ну и как вернуть хотя бы одну из ОС в рабочее состояние?

И да, SecureBoot не отрубается, он включён перманентно:

```
Secure Boot State: Enabled (immutable)
OS Type: Other OS
```

Версия UEFI - 8601, дата - 07/25/2002

Пробую пересоздать EFI раздел для Windows по гайду отсюда: http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/. Не помогает, EFI раздел не виден и лезет GRUB...

efibootmgr не спасает:

```
root@linuxlite6-live: ~ # efibootmgr -c -L "Windows11" -d /dev/sdb -p 1 -l 'EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Справился очень радикальным методом (можно было конечно обойтись `badblocks`, но я сделал так):

1.Бэкап Windows:

```
# dd if=/dev/sdc2 of=microsoft_reserved.img
# dd if=/dev/sdc3 of=win11_rootfs.img
# gparted 
# пересоздал таблицу разделов и разделы на диске. При этом я сделал все В ТОЧНОСТИ как ранее, байт в байт.
# mount -t ntfs -o remove_hiberfile,ro win11_rootfs.img /mnt
# для сноса hiberfile.sys
# dd if=win11_rootfs.img of=/dev/sdc2
```

И затем переустановил EFI загрузчик.